# Error de permisos android Expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Pues al intentar subir mi apk me manda este error:

Tu APK o Android App Bundle usa permisos que requieren una política de privacidad: (android.permission.CAMERA, android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, android.permission.READ_CONTACTS).

Segun lei debo de hacer esto:

```
"permissions": [
    "CAMERA",
    "RECORD_AUDIO",
    "READ_PHONE_STATE",
    "READ_CONTACTS",
    "READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
    "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
    "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE",
    "com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT",
    "com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT"
  ]
```

No quiero hacer detach de mi proyecto, espero haya alguna solución.

Answer (score 0):

Para el que tenga el mismo problema solo hay que poner los permisos vacio:

```
permissions:[]
```

Comment: Esto en realidad no es una solución que sucedería si requirieras algún permiso?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es proporcionar una url con alguna política de manejo de datos y privacidad, si necesitas acceder a la cámara especificas por que y en que casos y lo mismo si fuera acceso a la ubicación etc, algunos optan por publicar un pdf desde algun sitio gratuito como un drive al que se pueda acceder sin restricciones.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/323777)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).